How can I debug an SSH connection in Eclipse RSE
I can connect to the remote server with a ssh key pair, but I cannot get the connection to work with RSE using these keys. RSE ignores the certificate and insists on a password.
I’m looking for output like ssh -v
I’ve already worked around the ed25519 issue.
Nothing really helpful in the .log.
Eclipse
Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
Build id: 20240307-1437
RSE SSH Services    4.5.600.202401151828
Re: ed25519 issue:
https://cmljnelson.blog/2020/12/11/problem-using-ssh-keys-and-eclipses-remote-system-explorer/
"Invalid privatekey" when using JSch
My private key would not work with RSE with an OpenSSH header:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
But at least I would get an “Invalid key” message in the .log.
The new private key begins with:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY——
The private key is apparently valid but the connection fails and I can’t find any helpful information in the .log.

Worked around what ed25519 issue? How? It sounds as though you have not.

try setting -Djavax.net.debug=all on eclipse jvm settings. Also, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

No joy with this or  -Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake. UI insists on password, then nothing is logged.
!ENTRY org.eclipse.rse.ui !MESSAGE Connecting to [HOST] at port 22
